# How to make description of input field visible on hover

Tags: list, edit-form

I have a small request from my manager, saying that he wants to view the description of every field on hover in edit form.
 
I am aware that this function can be achieved through JQuery but i am not sure how.
if anyone can give an example then i can work it out!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. This [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240035/custom-complete-button/240039#240039) will help you understand how to capture the form items in SharePoint default list/library forms
2. Once, you can capture the items you can append some HTML hover elements using jQuery

Comment: i am still confused , but appreciate the help